# Move VBA "Set" function from Submodule to Module

Tags: vba

I maintain an application with a VBA backend (that I rarely need to touch) where I have found the following code in hundreds of different Modules/Subs that sets the contents of a system object (String) `Footer.Banner.FilterString` to the contents of global variable `User.Filter.CurrentValue`.  This applies whatever filter string is in `User.Filter.CurrentValue` to a list in the "footer" of the application.

```
Private Sub Whatever()
    Dim Banner As Object
    Set Banner = System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")
    Banner.FilterString = User.Filter.CurrentValue
End Sub
```

I want to clean this up so the object-setting occurs at the module level (by reference presumably), rather than repeating in hundreds of Subs, so each Sub that needs to update the Banner can contain only the following.

```
Private Sub Whatever()
    Banner.FilterString = User.Filter.CurrentValue
End Sub
```

Eventually I will create an `Filter_OnChange()` function/Sub that will let me remove all of the other instances completely.

---

This is as far as I have gotten, (with an "Invalid use of Property" error) but not even sure if I'm on the right path.  I can create Modules/Class Modules, but would prefer not to do that if possible.  Any suggestions?

```
Option Explicit
'Public Banner As Object
'Set Banner = System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")

Public Property Set Banner(ByRef pBanner As Object)
    Set pBanner = System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")
End Property
    
Private Sub Filter_OnChange()
    'Set Banner = System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")
    Banner.FilterString = User.Filter.CurrentValue
End Sub
```

---

### EDIT

Thanks to [@Storax's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6600940/storax) last example (Object), I've come up with the following **that works**! (in the 'base' module - didn't even need to create a separate module!!). Guess I just needed to change my **Set** to **Get**

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Banner() As Object
    Set Banner = System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")
End Property

Private Sub Filter_OnChange()
    Banner.FilterString = User.Filter.CurrentValue
End Sub
```

but I have a couple clarifying questions:

1. I ommitted the `If` code in `Public Property Get` as below.  Is this a problem/bad form?

```
'If getBanner Is Nothing Then
    Set Banner = System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")
'Else
'    Set Banner = getBanner
'End If
```

2. I omitted `Public Property Set` completely, and this works.  Is it unnecessary?
3. This solution causes changes in User.Filter.CurrentValue to update System.FindObject("Footer.Banner"), but not the other way around.  I suppose I can figure out how to make it bidirectional on my own, but suggestions are welcome if it's obvious to someone else.  Is it possible to permanently synchronize/ "alias" two objects?  Should I just duplicate my solution in reverse?  I want to be able to update *either* object and have the *other* one update automatically.

Comment: ad 1) That depends on your needs and difficult to tell, at least for me, because I do not know anything about `System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")` ad 2) `Set` is only neccessary if you want to change `Banner` via `Set` but in your case it seems you only need `get`. ad 3) I do not know because I do not know anything about `System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you after but you can use properties in ***normal*** modules as well

Have a look at the following code which you put in a normal module, i.e. you use **Insert/Module** (Do not use Insert/Class Module!)

```
Option Explicit

Dim mSystem As Variant

Public Property Get myValue() As Variant
    myValue = mSystem
End Property

Public Property Let myValue(ByVal newValue As Variant)
    mSystem = newValue
End Property
```

In order to initialize it you could use the workbook open event

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    myValue = "Start"
End Sub
```

And this is just a test

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestIt()
    
    ' Run first the workbook open event otherwise myValue will be empty
    Debug.Print myValue
    myValue = "new Value"
    Debug.Print myValue
    
End Sub
```

Another simple example (not really useful in the real world) with an object. Again, put this code into a normal module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mXl  As Excel.Application

Public Property Get myXL() As Excel.Application
    If mXl Is Nothing Then
        Set myXL = New Excel.Application
    Else
        Set myXL = mXl
    End If
End Property

Public Property Set myXL(ByVal newXL As Excel.Application)
    Set mXl = newXL
End Property
```

And a test could be

```
Sub Testxl()
    Debug.Print myXL.Version
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm looking into this.  I'm so confused about Set/Let/Get.  I read I needed to use Set when "setting"  an object..  Somewhere I need to accomplish the equivalent of "Set myPublicObject = System.FindObject("Footer.Banner")" (by reference presumably)

Comment: Well, you rock.  I was able to get it working based on your last (Object) example - It definitely was useful in the real world!  I appended my question to show my results and ask a few clarifying questions.  Any chance you could comment (or append to your answer in response)?  P.S. I'm using a third-party application that uses VBA behind the scenes (mostly auto-generated), not Excel.  P.P.S SO needs a "Donate" button on answers!